# Filtering nodes in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 force layout where I want to filter the graph according to a checkbox. I have a data structure like this:

```
 "nodes": [{
    "ID": [
      "randomID1"
    ], 
    "authors": [
      "data1", 
      "data6", 
      "data5"
    ], 
    "type2": "randomType", 
    "name": "someName1"
  }, 
  {
    "ID": [
      "randomID2"
    ], 
    "type1": [
      "data1", 
      "data2", 
      "data3", 
      "data4"
    ], 
    "type2": "randomType", 
    "name": "some name 2"
  }]
```

I tried to implement these two functions which I found on the web, in order to compare the string in the array partially, but it throws up an error o.includes is not a function

```
function createFilter() {
        //alert("createFilter");
        d3.select(".filterContainer").selectAll("div")
          .data(["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6"])
          .enter()  
          .append("div")
          .attr("class", "checkbox-container")

          .append("label")
          .each(function (d) {
                // create checkbox for each data
                d3.select(this).append("input")
                  .attr("type", "checkbox")
                  .attr("id", function (d) {
                      return "chk_" + d;
                   })
                  .attr("checked", true)
                  .on("click", function (d, i) {
                      // register on click event
                      var lVisibility = this.checked ? "visible" : "hidden";
                      filterGraph(d, lVisibility);
                   })
                d3.select(this).append("span")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d;
                    });
        });
        $("#sidebar").show();
    } 

function filterGraph(aType, aVisibility) {
        // change the visibility of the connection link
        link.style("visibility", function (o) {
            var lOriginalVisibility = $(this).css("visibility");
            return o.includes(aType) ? aVisibility : lOriginalVisibility;
        });

        // change the visibility of the node
        // if all the links with that node are invisible, the node should also be invisible
        // otherwise if any link related to that node is visible, the node should be visible
        circle.style("visibility", function (o, i) {
            var lHideNode = true;
            link.each(function (d, i) {
                if (d.source === o || d.target === o) {
                    if ($(this).css("visibility") === "visible") {
                        lHideNode = false;
                        // we need show the text for this circle
                        d3.select(d3.selectAll(".nodeText")[0][i]).style("visibility", "visible");
                        return "visible";
                    }
                }
            });
            if (lHideNode) {
                // we need hide the text for this circle 
                d3.select(d3.selectAll(".nodeText")[0][i]).style("visibility", "hidden");
                return "hidden";
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `o` is a string and not an object?

Comment: I suppose, you are using this [example](https://github.com/zhanghuancs/D3.js-Link-Filter). And, as @GerardoFurtado mentioned, `o` is an object, which does not have an `.includes()` method. That's why the original code uses `return o.type === aType ? aVisibility : lOriginalVisibility;` for string comparison.